# Logging Duplicate Information in a Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, logging

Say you had the following arrays:

```
    int[] x = new int[6] {2,4,6,8,10,12};
    int[] y = new int[6] {3,6,9,12,15,18};
```

If you wanted to print the values of the array that are identical, 6 and 12 in this example, what would be the most efficient way to do this in C#? Would there be a difference with other data types like strings or booleans?

Comment: Gets the needed task done in the fewest lines necessary and with the lowest needed extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to find the matched elements

```
int[] x = new int[6] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };
int[] y = new int[6] { 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 };

foreach (int i in x)
{
    if (y.Contains(i))
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(i);//Print Matched items
    }
}
```

As long as datatype is same in both arrays it will work fine.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer is `O(n * m)`, which is `O(n^2)` when n = m. Creating a hashset with the contents of one of the arrays and checking instead for items in the hashset from the other array is `O(n + m)`, which is `O(n)` when n = m. Doing so requires allocating `O(n)` additional storage on the one hand, on the other it will complete before the end of the universe when n is large. For arrays with six elements, any solution will work. For arrays with six million, the marked answer will not. Both sets of code are trivial.

The implementation can be done in two lines.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(x);
var inBoth = y.Where(t => hashSet.Contains(t));
```

Here is a complete program demonstrating why an `O(n^2)` solution is inadequite for any real size of problem. If you want to convince yourself that both implementations function correctly, reduce the size of `totalItems` to ~100,000 and it will complete in reasonable time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Solution
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int totalItems = 1000000;

        var rng = new Random();
        var foo = Enumerable.Range(0, totalItems).Select(x => rng.Next(1, totalItems / 2)).ToArray();
        var bar = Enumerable.Range(0, totalItems).Select(x => rng.Next(1, totalItems / 2)).ToArray();

        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        var foobar = new HashSet<int>(foo);
        var inBoth = bar.Count(t => foobar.Contains(t));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + inBoth);

        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        inBoth = bar.Count(t => foo.Contains(t));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + " " + inBoth);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```